# Can I suppress translation for a specific phrase in an Google Play Store app description?

Tags: android, google-play

When publishing an app in the [Google Play Developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/), I've added a short and full description in English. I'm distributing the app to all countries, and Google seems to translate the short description text automatically. This is by and large helpful, but the description contains a couple of phrases that I don't want translated. Is it possible to prevent translation of specific phrases by surrounding them with quotes or anything like that?

Comment: I search on internet but i dont found anything...so i guess answer is NO